# onStartCommand() method in Bound Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I am new to Android and I am learning about BoundService(local binding).

I studied how to connect to a service and everything was fine until I saw this example.

Inside `BoundService.java`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    startRandomNumberGenerator(); // a method that generates random number in a separate thread.

}
```

I understand that the `Started Service` and `BoundService` are not separate stuff.

However, the about service was called from the activity using `bindService(...)`.

1. Will the onStartService() method be called if we start a service using `bindService(...)` ?
2. Is it a good practice to override `onStartCommand()` method if we are creating a bound service ?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `onStartCommand(...)` is practically useless (not called) if you are using `bindService(...)` to run your `Service`. That said, override `onBind(...)` if you are using `bindService(...)` or `onStartCommand(...)` if you are using `startService(...)` or both if you are using it together.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind a service, that service will continue to run for the lifecycle of your activity.  If you then call `startService`, your service will receive the arguments that you pass, and can also continue to run beyond the activity's lifecycle.